# PHP feof() False as first argument

Tags: php, feof

I ended up “resolving” someone else’s code issue since the site was down and we couldn’t get a hold of them, but I don’t use PHP and I think this is working, but not for the right reasons:

They have something like:

```
$file = ../somedir/somefile.txt;
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
while (!feof($fh)) {
$line = fget(...
```

But the page wasn’t loading.

Based on the error in the log, I ended up changing the `feof` line to:

```
while (feof(False, $fh)) {
```

Which actually appears to have resolved the issue, but after looking at documentation for `feof()`, I don’'t think what I did was right at all.

What is that impact of adding `False` as the first argument to PHP's `feof()` function?

**Update**:  The log error was `feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in` I took Boolean to mean True False, which is why I set the False as first arg.

Comment: Can you show what the error in the log was? That will help in determining what the best solution is.

Comment: I can't see how the code could still be functioning (specifically the body of the original loop including `fgets()`.  You have changed the negative condition in the loop to a positive one, but `feof()` accepts only one parameter. PHP would be throwing tons of E_WARNING as `Warning: feof() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given`

Comment: agreed, feof only takes one parameter, a resource. if anything, this should have caused more problems.

Comment: The error in the logs was "feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <filename>"

Comment: Ahhhhhh! The original error _feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given_ indicates that the `fopen()` call before it failed and returned `false` instead of a file handle resource. You need to fix the `fopen()` to make sure it can read the file.

Comment: After `$fh = fopen(....)` check `if ($fh) { // loop over the file } else { // Oops, an error opening the file }`

Comment: So am I just making it circumvent the file?  This code must be really messed up then to not need this block, because other blocks supposedly depend on it.

Comment: The fopen() points to a variable which contains a relative path i.e. ../somedir/file.txt is that problematic?

Comment: If fopen() is unable to read the file, check the permissions on the file and that the path to the file is correct.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal The relative path isn't problematic, but the file it leads to might be. It might not be readable by the web server user, or it might just not even exist.

Comment: No, it exists and is readable by apache, I've checked that.

Comment: _“I took Boolean to mean True False, which is why I set the False as first arg.”_ – If you can not even interpret the error message the right way, then you probably shouldn’t be messing with this at all …

Comment: @CBroe Probably not, but a site was down, no one else was available, I was able to understand what the block that was throwing errors was trying to do.  I realized fairly quickly that I misinterpreted the error, and that is why this question exists.  I want to know what the result of that misinterpretation actually was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is that impact of adding `False` as the first argument to PHP's
>   `feof()` function?

Well, here is what [`feof`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php) documentation says:

> Tests for end-of-file on a file pointer.

And since there is only one parameter allowed in the function as indicated here:

```
bool feof ( resource $handle )
```

The `False` you are setting basically is telling the script:

```
while ([the file handle doesn’t equals false do this]) {
```

So you are basically short-circuiting the logic in some way. But without seeing the full code or error messages it’s 100% unclear what impact doing something like this would have on overall application behavior.

**UPDATE:** Since you now say the error log says:

```
feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
```

That basically means the problem is the `$file` that you are attempting to open and then create a file handle with `$fh` does’t exist or can’t be read:

```
$file = ../somedir/somefile.txt;
$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
```

The best solution for you now is to wrap the condition in another conditional like this:

```
$file = ../somedir/somefile.txt;
if (file_exists($filename)) {
  $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
  while (!feof($fh)) {
  $line = fget(...
}
```

But now looking at your code is that line `$file = ../somedir/somefile.txt;` correct?  Shouldn’t it be:

```
$file = '../somedir/somefile.txt';
```

So your code would look like this:

```
$file = '../somedir/somefile.txt';
if (file_exists($filename)) {
  $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
  while (!feof($fh)) {
  $line = fget(...
}
```

But past any of that, I would check if the actual file `../somedir/somefile.txt` exists and is readable by your script. It could be that the location changed or the permissions or user connected to that file has been changed. That is most likely the underlying cause of the `feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in` error.

Comment: This error stopped once I added my misguided False to feof.